How to load a python module installed in the executable folder? (C++)
I have an install structure like this:
install_folder\

app.exe
lib.dll
python\

kitsu.py



And I am trying to execute some functions in my application from the file kitsu.py.
My C++ code is like this:
( main.cpp )
  TCHAR curr_path[MAX_PATH]; 
  DWORD length = GetModuleFileName(nullptr, curr_path, MAX_PATH);
  PathRemoveFileSpec(curr_path, MAX_PATH);
  PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue, * presult, * sys, * python_folder, * fromlist, * syspathres;

  // Initialize the Python Interpreter
  Py_Initialize();

  // Build the name object
  pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"kitsu");
  python_folder = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)".python");

  PyObject* py_curr_path = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)curr_path);
  char command[MAX_PATH];
  sprintf(command, "sys.path.append(%s)", curr_path);

  PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
  PyRun_SimpleString(command);

  fromlist = PyTuple_Pack(1, python_folder);

  // Load the module object
  pModule = PyImport_ImportModuleEx((char*)"kitsu", nullptr, nullptr, fromlist);
  PyObject* init_kitsu = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"init_kitsu");

  presult = PyObject_CallObject(init_kitsu, nullptr); 

(Please excuse any formal inconsitencies as this is early stage code.)
The application crashes because pModule is nullptr.
Why is it failing to retrieve the module?

But you add the current directory to sys.path, not the python subdirectory?

good point, I don't know why I didnt think of it, let me try like that

BTW no it didnt work, anyone has any other suggestion?

"it didn't work" is a terrible, inexcusable diagnosis. Edit your question with the code you have now. Did you correct for the missing quotes around the %s ?
